# Canonical for common new-user R errors with Logistic, Linear regression, GLM

Tags: discussion, canonical

What should be the canonical Q&A for these common new-user R logistic and linear regression Errors? Let's identify, and then please help close-as-duplicate.

- **trying to predict a numeric variable with Logistic Regression**

  1. [logistic regression: Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105279/logistic-regression-error-in-evalfamilyinitialize-y-values-must-be-0-y)
  2. [Logistic Regression on factor: Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546658/logistic-regression-on-factor-error-in-evalfamilyinitialize-y-values-must). Cannot yet make canonical because no answer accepted.
  3. a duplicate, with glm [Error in glm “Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628881/error-in-glm-error-in-evalfamilyinitialize-y-values-must-be-0-y-1)
- **trying to do regression when variables have NAs or are factors**

  1. definitely need a good canonical
  2. not a great canonical because user is using plsRglm package, not that that matters really [Logistic regression with NAs and factors returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625174/logistic-regression-with-nas-and-factors-returns-error)
- **Linear Regression: when and how to use Box-Cox or other transform to make response variable normal**

  1. need a canonical
- **extract standard errors of coefficients from logistic regressions**

  1. [Extract all standard errors of coefficients from list of logistic regressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045032/extract-all-standard-errors-of-coefficients-from-list-of-logistic-regressions)
- many other topics