# What's the recourse when duplicate answers don't mean duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

I found a different solution for a problem that I've seen on various different questions. I don't think they're all duplicates, but my answer serves anyone encountering them equally well.

Once my solution was different from everyone else's. I decided to reply and copied the solution to post on the other threads with similar issues. My answer got *deleted* by Samuel Liew, saying that I should reference my other post instead of copying the answer.

I did just that and got downvoted twice on that answer.

[This is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516557/multiple-avplayers-with-avplayerlayers-disappears-second-time-push-viewcontrolle/50109056?noredirect=1#comment87240051_50109056)

After that I also got downvoted in another question that I posted the link to my original answer

[This is the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844573/presentedviewcontroller-changes-orientation-of-presenting-view-controller-break/50118050?noredirect=1#comment87256818_50118050)

And again on the other related question.

[This is the third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073127/nested-uistackviews-broken-constraints/50118934?noredirect=1#comment87255192_50118934)

With all of these, I was just trying to help other people who may open storyboard programmatically using presentViewController that doing it with showViewController could fix all those bizarre issues just like it did for me.

This way moderators just downvoting because they have different ways of thinking how the answer should be... you are making the users not reading my answer that could fix their problem and you are also discouraging me to help other people.

Comment: So you posted essentially the same answer to more than a few similar questions? That's actually something we strongly discourage, but the problem is, the UI doesn't do anything to inform folks of that.

Comment: if it's the same answer, does that mean that all these questions are duplicates?

Comment: No because people think that source of the problem could be nested Stacks or something with constraints and the origin for all those different  layout being broken was the way the storyboard was presented/shown

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking here? Is it okay to do what you did? or why would people downvote for it? Or what should you do when you have an answer that applies to multiple different questions? Although you did explain what happened, it's not clear what question you're asking about it.

Comment: I could've sworn we had a duplicate of this scenario floating around here somewhere.  My Google-fu is weak.  There's prior art on what to do with copying answers across multiple questions; the long-and-short of it is, **don't**; if the question can be answered the same way then it's a smell that it's a dupe.

Comment: What Samuel probably meant is that you need to provide a full fledged answer to a specific question and at best link to an answer or other sources as a reference or background. Just imagine someone who visits a question because that describes their issue. Then each answer is barely more then a link. That visitor could have better kept their Google search results open instead of loading the Question and Answer page.

Comment: the questions are NOT duplicates... my answer is just for users to check one possible source of the problem. I too was getting errors of constraints and trying to fix the issue elsewhere. So people could really have different problems that may be solved by my answer

Comment: So in this particular case what should I do? Just be afraid of expressing my experience over different threads with the threat of losing my rep for answering in different threads? Should I make a custom answer for every thread so the answer doesn't look the same? Should I never try to answer different threads with the same solution? (even if the problems are a bit different between them)

Comment: If you want to answer questions, then, by all means, answer them.  Just make sure that your answer is specific to the question being asked.

Comment: So you were saying that the questions weren't related to each other yet you were answering them in the same way...?

Comment: @Makoto Looks like one of those scenarios where one thing fixes lots of issues that _seem_ unrelated outside of the context of the fix (thus unlikely to be thought of as duplicates) - it does happen, actually IOS / Android is where it happens most.

Comment: You should never copy the whole answer to multiple questions. Tailor the answers for each question if the questions are different. provide links to your other (similar) answers to provide context in case the OP stumbles on your answer but wonders if it is applicable in a different context.

Comment: Yeah, that's something along the lines of what I was trying to nail down @TimPost.

Comment: Makoto I'm not affirming that.. I'm saying that the source of the problem COULD be related. When working with iOS constraints, Autolayout inserts some constraints. The symptom of all threads I replied were similar and one possible solution (Only in case a storyboard was created with presentVC and not showVC) in my case 
 that was the source. I just posted on threads that had similar constraints conflicts for users to be aware of how their storyboard is being created. Because both methods should work accordingly to Apple but one does and the other makes this bizzare errors all around.

Comment: Could a feature be added to stack overflow like for us to mark answers that could be checked for the solution of another thread?  Like in this case that errors are different ( even on my tests ) If I could just mark on all those threads like check this answer that could be the source of that bizzare error?  I think it would solve this problem of people copying and trying to answer other threads that are not duplicates (errors are different) and everyone could check that like "pre requisite answer"

Comment: We use duplicate closure as a way to say that your question is *answered* somewhere else, even if the questions aren't entirely the same, but can be decomposed to match the same answer(s) as someone else's approach.  So I'm still thinking that this is more along the lines of, "Maybe you should've closed these as dupes", but there has to be something here I'm not seeing...

Comment: Makoto if you read the threads I mentioned you can see people are searching for completely different things because the errors leads people to float around. My team thought of 10 different things that could have caused the problem and only after cleaning all possibilities that I tried this fix (which was a long shot) that we noticed the bizarre behavior that it avalanched... and one is looking for Stack objects causing the problem others on the video player... 2 completely different things and the source was something completely unrelated

Comment: (Note: The references are to answers (for unknown reasons, references to seemingly random comments to the OP's answers). All three answers have now been deleted.)

Answer (score 17):

You're getting downvotes because you're cross-posting the same answer to multiple questions. That's not allowed. Even in link-only form.

You can certainly link to other answers as reference for a new one. But if the link is so critical to getting the answer, then it's not a separate answer.

If a copy-and-paste answer would answer someone's question, then that question is almost certainly a duplicate of the other. And you should flag the question as such.

Comment: Well but that's not the case. Those threads could really have different problems because they are asking different questions. My answer could fix some of them but could also be something completely different. I just wanted to share my experience in the case of anyone had a storyboard being opened programmatically to just confirm if they are opening it with showViewController instead of presentViewContoller. That was a long shot that my team lost 2 days looking elsewhere for the source of the problem

Comment: Even if the questions are not perfectly *duplicates*, but only "strongly related" (or the problem is caused by the same mistake) : One can consider leaving a *comment* in the other questions, along the lines of "I wrote a solution for a similar problem here, maybe you find it helpful: `[link]`". Writing an answer that is **good** is difficult: It has to *exactly* fit the question (and really *answer* the question).

Comment: yeah Marco13 I did just that because of the deleted answer (the one that I copied) suggested to do just that.. and I got downvoted my other moderators in the same thread saying that I shouldn't have done that :/

Answer (score 8):

The experience here needs some tweaking, both from the user and moderator perspectives.

We detect duplicate content and raise a flag. The flag essentially means *Hey moderators, go see if we've got some duplicate questions that could possibly be merged, or perhaps a serial spammer on our hands!* (as one answer posted many times could indicate either, or both).

Clearing that flag effectively takes on an average of 10 - 15 minutes *per*, because it does unearth some good duplicate candidates, and more often than not, merge candidates. Merging means a lot of cleanup, so the answers that remain (from many questions) make sense under the one remaining question.

The solution here I think is to find a way to detect this, offload it to the community, and make merging / unmarking of questions straight forward and safe enough to put at another rep level (say, maybe, 30k?).

*Then* we trip in the UI telling people *hey, flag for "my answer answers this too"* or somehow convert it, and let high rep users in those tags sort it out. There should also be a signal for someone of sufficient rep to say "Nah, I know what I'm doing, these are different questions but my answer still applies" - that *does* happen sometimes.

Nicol is correct, the behavior is not allowed, but we don't discourage it in the user experience and every time we hear about someone getting tripped up in it and don't optimize it better, kittens get sad.

I really feel like we could be handling this better on both sides, to be honest, and free moderators up to handle other flags. In the time it takes to handle one valid 'duplicate answer' flag, they could handle up to 25 or 30 of another kind.

Note: It's *best* if you adjust the answer to fit the questions as you find them, but then again, depending on the answer (if it's mostly code, or a comprehensive "this is actually related to something you wouldn't think it was related to" bit), that's not always necessary.

Comment: "the behavior is not allowed" what about questions that are not duplicate, but the solution just happens to be the same thing? Like "restart the system" or "install virtualbox guest additions".

Comment: @Braiam That's actually the exception in the majority of these cases. But I think we need a button that says "Hey I'm a grown up, I know what I'm doing, these are different questions" to send that additional signal once we better inform users that it's _strongly_ discouraged as they try doing it. But, then it starts looking a bit like that mousetrap game again.

Comment: For the record, personally if I have to rewrite all the answers to one question to match the other, they are not candidates for merging in my book. I've honestly never encountered a single case of someone posting carbon copy answers where the questions themselves were carbon copy reposts. The closest I've seen is one where someone knowingly (but not maliciously) posted a carbon copy answer prefaced with "This was originally posted to <link to previous question>" - and I sorted that out by deleting one of the questions, not merging them, because one of them simply wasn't needed anymore :P

Comment: I've also encountered *vanishingly few* cases where carbon copies of a single answer could *ideally* address two separate questions with no room for tailoring. And I'm inclined to call that vanishingly few, none - if it wasn't for the fact that my hazy memory insists that I've seen such cases before.

Comment: [Duplicate answers should be blocked rather than just flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210373) meta.se 4.5 years ago [meta-tag:status-review]

Answer (score 3):

<sub>(Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with the technologies involved here - so I cannot say whether the questions are only "related", or whether they are indeed *duplicates*, or whether your answer is an appropriate answer for any (or even *all* of them))</sub>

The reasons of why the answers have been downvoted are already explained in the other answers. The main point is: **If** the same answer fits multiple questions, then one might consider the questions as duplicates of each other.

In any case: An answer that only links to another answer is likely not perceived as a "good" answer **per se**. (The answer that it links to may be great - but the answer that only *contains* the link is not!)

There is no clear definition of what constitutes a "duplicate". As an overly suggestive example: There may be **many** questions caused by something like a `NullPointerException`. And the answers will always be "different" in some way. But they all boil down to the same problem.

If you think that your answer fits multiple questions, then you could consider proposing it as a **Canonical Answer** (see [What is a canonical question/answer, and what is their purpose?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) )

(But note that writing a **good canonical answer** is usually more difficult than writing a good answer for itself...)

---

A recent example of such a case, just to give you an idea of what this may look like: [Canonical for common new-user R errors with Logistic, Linear regression, GLM](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366957/canonical-for-common-new-user-r-errors-with-logistic-linear-regression-glm?cb=1)

Comment: while not wrong I doubt if this answer is useful/applicable in the given context.

Comment: @rene I think the point that *"The answer that it links to may be great - but the answer that only contains the link is not!"* is important, and was not mentioned yet. Beyond that, you might be right, but I didn't dare to even try and sort out the difficulties of "duplicates and canonicals" in a single answer... ;-)

Comment: Yeah, duplicates and canonicals is a real challenge. It might turn out to be easier to sort out the unwelcoming nature of SO ;)